# Closing an .ui file on a click of a button (pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need my dialog box to close when the ok button is clicked. How do I do that ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the ok button a button you created?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created the button you should be able to just set the button click event as follows:

`button.clicked.connect(self.close)` where `button` is the button name.

Although since you did not provide any code with your question it's hard to know if this is what you're asking for...